# Can Dask parallelize contents inside a function?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have a function written in python. 
I want to know if a code inside that function is parallelizable, can I somehow parallelize the code inside that function without making dask API calls inside that function?

I was thinking of whether dask.delayed could help me in this. But I think it parallelizes the multiple executions of a function, but I want to parallelize the inner contents of a function. Is it even possible using dask?

Answer (score 1):

No, dask does not auto-parallelize your Python code.  You will have to use Dask constructs like dask.delayed to parallelize your code.

Comment: And using dask.delayed, my whole function will execute on a single node. Can it execute on multiple nodes, using dask.delayed?

Comment: Each dask.delayed call can be run independently on different machines, yes.  I recommend reading through http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html or trying examples at https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/dask/dask-examples/master?filepath=delayed.ipynb